# How do you control the height of the buttons on an Alert Dialog in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have the following code.
How can I make the Neutral Button twice as tall, or Just set it's height for that matter.
Right now it's too thin and the users are having trouble clicking on it.
I don't want to roll my own dialog if I can help it.

```
int SizeIndex = CurrentState.BaseItem.Sub.indexOf(CurrentState.BaseItem.GetDefaultSize());
CharSequence[] csItems = CurrentState.BaseItem.subNamesToArray();

new AlertDialog.Builder(CurrentState.Activity)              
    .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setTitle(R.string.prompt_SelectSize)
    .setSingleChoiceItems(csItems,SizeIndex, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    CurrentState.SelectedSize = (ItemSize) CurrentState.BaseItem.Sub.get(which);                                                    
                }
            })
            .setNeutralButton(R.string.alert_dialog_Done, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    if(CurrentState.SelectedSize == null)
                    {
                        CurrentState.SelectedSize  = CurrentState.BaseItem.GetDefaultSize();
                    }
                    CurrentState.Next();
                    dialog.cancel();                        
                }
            })              
            .show();
```

Comment: Maybe using the android:minWidth and android:minHeight in the layout xml can be of help? Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: (Unable to post answer for 8 hours as New User so here it is)  I solved this with this code...

But you have to call it AFTER you have called alertdialog.show() due to an Android Issue.

            Button button = (Button) alertdialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL); 
         if (button != null)         button.setHeight(HDSystem.getInteger(eSetting.ButtonHeight));